# ADD DIv and reduce div have proper alignment of field css

Tags: jquery, css, jsp, jquery-ui

Below Image show The UserInterface of My Page [image]

There is two Drop-Down and and two text box,how to align them with + and - image

and on plus click it show as it is another same div which have all four element (i used clone method from w3 school but it does not full fill requirement the value are same to subsequent div)
below is my jsp page

```
mipage.jsp...............................................

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>


<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="label"%>
<%-- <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
 --%>

<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Minority Interest</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var companyName = '${companyName}';
    var companyId = '${companyId}';
</script>


<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="<%=Config.getStaticURL()%>resources/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.23/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="<%=Config.getStaticURL()%>resources/css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="<%=Config.getStaticURL()%>resources/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />

<script
    src="<%=Config.getStaticURL()%>resources/js/consolidation/transaction/addAquisition.js"></script>
<script
    src="<%=Config.getStaticURL()%>resources/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.23/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script
    src="<%=Config.getStaticURL()%>resources/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.23/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<%=Config.getStaticURL()%>resources/plugins/jquery/blockUI/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<script
    src="<%=Config.getStaticURL()%>resources/js/consolidation/minorityinterest/minorityinterest.js"></script>
<script
    src="<%=Config.getStaticURL()%>resources/js/consolidation/minorityinterest/MI.js"></script>

<style type="text/css" media="all">
.MICss {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #d9e4ee;
    height: 65px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    width: 97%;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span11">
            <h4 class="page_title">
                <label:message code="label.alignment.title1" />
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="backBtn" class="span1 hide">
            <span class="back_button"> <a class="backBtnClass" href="#"
                onclick="backBtnClick()"> <i class="icon-circle-arrow-left"></i>&nbsp;
                    <label:message code='consolidation.btnBack' />
            </a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <div id="selectDiv" class="row-fluid">
        <div id="cmpDiv" class="span3">
            <select onmouseover="disableSelect(this)" id="cmpCombo"
                class="input-block-level" disabled>
                <option title="${companyName}" value='${companyId}'>${companyName}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="parentCmpDiv" class="span3">
            <select onmouseover="disableSelect(this)" id="parentCmp"
                name="parentCmp" onchange="changeParentCmp()"
                class="input-block-level">
                <option value='' disabled="disabled">Select child Company</option>
                <c:forEach items="${parentCmpList}" var="element">
                    <option value="${element.companyId}">${element.companyName}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="fyDiv" class="span3">
            <select onmouseover="disableSelect(this)" id="financialYearId"
                name="financialYearId" onchange="fillRpCombo();"
                class="input-block-level">
                <option value='' disabled="disabled">Select Financial Year</option>
                <c:forEach items="${fyList}" var="element">
                    <option value="${element.yearId}">${element.yearName}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="rpDiv" class="span3">
            <select onmouseover="disableSelect(this)" id="reportingPeriodId"
                name="reportingPeriodId" class="input-block-level"
                onchange="showMasterDivMin();">
                <option value='' disabled="disabled">Select Reporting
                    Period</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--  middle conatiner div vaibhav -->


    <div class="row-fluid marginbottom10 margintop10 hide" id="masterDiv"
        style="height: 450px; width: 100%; border: 1px solid #000;">
        <div class="row-fluid margintop10 hide" id="messageDivInner">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="alert-success alert" align="center" id="messageInner"></div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="preacq0" class="MICss">
            <div id="linkopen">
                <div class="span5">
                    <spring:message code="MinorityInterest.elementName" />

                    <select id="glListName">

                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="span5">

                    <select>
                        <option value="select">select</option>
                        <option value="Debit">Debit</option>
                        <option value="Credit">Credit</option>
                    </select>
                </div>


                <div class="span5">

                    <label class="abc" style="margin-bottom: 1px;"> <input
                        type="text" name="abc">
                </div>
                <div class="span5">

                    <label class="abc" style="margin-bottom: 1px;"> <input
                        type="text" name="abc">
                </div>





            <div class="span2" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                <div class="add_remove">
                    <a><img onclick="addMoreMin()"
                        src="<%=Config.getStaticURL()%>resources/img/Add-field.png" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="add_remove">

                    <img src="<%=Config.getStaticURL()%>resources/img/remove-field.png" />
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">

        function removeDiv(ab){

             var add = '<div id="preacq'+ind+'" class="MICss"><div class="span5"><label><spring:message code="consolidation.elementName" /></label><form:select name ="glElementId" multiple="false" class="input-block-level" path="glElementId" items="${classificationEleList}" itemValue="elementId" itemLabel="elementName" id="elementIdXYZ" onchange="removeElemError(this.id);"/></div><div class="span5"><label><spring:message
                code="consolidation.amount" /></label><input id="addElementTotalXYZ" type="text" class="input-block-level abc" title="Enter positive value for Credit and negative value for Debit"  autocomplete="off" name="glAmount"   onblur="checkDecimal(this.id) , totalCount(this.value)"/></div><div class="span2" style="margin-top: 15px;"><div class="add_remove"><a><img onclick="addMore()" src="<%=Config.getStaticURL()%>resources/img/Add-field.png"></a></div><div class="add_remove"><a><img id = '+ab+' onclick="funcDef(this.id)" src="<%=Config.getStaticURL() %>
                resources/img/remove-field.png"></a></div></div></div>';
                    return add;
                }
            </script>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>

    <div id="entryDiv" class="hide" style="height: 100%;"></div>
    <div id="permanentEntryDiv" class="hide" style="height: 100%;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

if any other file required tell..
I am newbie in UI please help me out

Thanks In advance

Comment: here is a nice [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/QLfxs/) example of using .clone() in jquery

Comment: @steven iseki thank you, i did already please read my whole question,